# Can I use Newtonsoft.Json with CosmosDb v3?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have followed [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support) to have `Newtonsoft` used in my Blazor Server project along with CosmosDb **v3**.

Thus my `Startup.cs` specifies several settings and converters.

```cs
  services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ISubfileConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new ISubunitConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IElementConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IMetadataConverter());
    });

    services.AddSingleton<ICosmosSrcDocService>(InitializeCosmosSrcClientInstance(Configuration.GetSection("SourceCosmosDb"))
                .GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

However, when I use `UpsertItemAsync()` it does not appear to be using it.

Is there a way I can tell CosmosDb in `Startup.cs`  to use this configuration?

**UPDATE with Cosmos configuration**

```cs
   CosmosClientBuilder clientBuilder = new CosmosClientBuilder(account, key);
   CosmosClient client = clientBuilder
      .WithConnectionModeDirect()
      .Build();
      CosmosTrgDocService cosmosDbService = new CosmosTrgDocService(client, databaseName, containerName);
```

Comment: You showed how you are configuring Newtonsoft on ASPNET, can you show how you are creating the CosmosClient? Are you customizing the serialization options there? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions.serializeroptions?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_CosmosClientOptions_SerializerOptions

Answer (score 3):

I found that `CosmosClientBuilder` has a `WithCustomSerializer()` method. That allowed me to figure out that you can derive a class from [`CosmosSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosserializer?view=azure-dotnet) and then pass that to the `WithCustomSerializer()` method.

When you override the `ToStream<T>` and `FromStream<T>` methods you can control the serialization. [Also see this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/63f4799b5eb7192401159548e346cb383570e07b/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs).

Comment: If using the `CosmosClientOptions` to initialize a `CosmosClient` then can use the `Serializer` property to set it analogously.

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on @phil answer which helped me out, I used the following approach which has solved the "Self referencing loop detected" error message I was trying to overcome (I didnt want to put the JsonIgnore attributes on my POCOs as per some other suggestions).

```
var client = new CosmosClientBuilder(databaseSettings.ConnectionString)
            .WithCustomSerializer(new CustomCosmosSerializer())
            .Build();
```

And the following serializer.

```
public class CustomCosmosSerializer : CosmosSerializer
{
    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;
    public CustomCosmosSerializer()
    {
        _serializer = new JsonSerializer
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        };
    }
    public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        using (stream)
        {
            if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                return (T)(object)(stream);
            }

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    return _serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
    {
        MemoryStream streamPayload = new MemoryStream();
        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(streamPayload, encoding: Encoding.Default, bufferSize: 1024, leaveOpen: true))
        {
            using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
                _serializer.Serialize(writer, input);
                writer.Flush();
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
        }

        streamPayload.Position = 0;
        return streamPayload;
    }
}
```